# How to reuse column alias in another column within same select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, column-alias

```
select pd.id
       ,[value 1] = Case
                    ----
                    End
       ,[value 2] = Case when [value 1] in ('test1', 'test2') Then 0
                    else [value 1] End
```

I am getting as invalid column when I try to use value 1 in value 2. Is there a possibility to use calculated [value 1] to be used in [value 2]

My current solution is to create a separate sp or view for value 1 but that's not what I want to do.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: The answer is no, not the way you're trying to do it. Either repeat the case expression, or have a derived table or cte returning value1.

Comment: As said, you cannot reference a computed column from another computed column - you can use a `view` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `APPLY` to define column aliases in the `FROM` clause -- a good place, in my opinion:

```
select pd.id v.value_1,
       (Case when value_1 in ('test1', 'test2') Then '0'
             else value_1
        End) as value_2
from pd cross apply
     (values ( case . . . )
     ) v(value_1);
```

Notes:

- Don't use identifier names that need to be escaped, hence `value_1` instead of `value 1`.
- `value_1` appears to be string.  The `case` expression for `value_2` should return a string, so `'0'` instead of `0`.
- I define table aliases using `as` after the expression.  This is the SQL standard, but there is nothing *per se* wrong with using `=`, which is SQL Server specific syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can select [value 1] with a select statement then write an outer query to select [value 1] and [value 2]

```
SELECT  [value 1], [value 2] = Case when [value 1] in ('test1', 'test2') Then 0
                                    else [value 1] End 
FROM
(
select pd.id
       ,[value 1] = Case
                    ----
                    End
FROM TABLENAME
)T
```

Or you can repeat the case statement for [value 1] within case statement of [value 2]

```
select pd.id
       ,[value 1] = Case
                    ----
                    End
       ,[value 2] = Case when ( Case
                    ----
                    End [value 1]) in ('test1', 'test2') Then 0
                    else ( Case
                    ----
                    End [value 1]
                              ) End
```